# C# asynchronous client socket problem - target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server (written in Python) which accepts connections on the TCP socket, port 10200 on my local Windows machine (127.0.0.1). I have tested it with telnet and with some other applications and it seems to be working (no firewall issues, etc.).

The TCP Socket client (which I have issues with) is written in C#. It tries to asynchronously establish a TCP connection to the above socket. The code snippet is as follows:

```cs
public void Connect (string host, int port) {  
    try { 
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry (host);
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint (ipAddress, port);

        state.socket = new Socket (ipAddress.AddressFamily, 
                                   SocketType.Stream,
                                   ProtocolType.Tcp);
        state.socket.ReceiveTimeout = TcpState.RecvTimeout;

        state.socket.BeginConnect (remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback (ConnectCallback), state);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.Log (e.ToString ());
        Disconnect ();
    }
}

// ...

private void ConnectCallback (IAsyncResult ar) {
    try {
 
        TcpState state = (TcpState) ar.AsyncState;

        state.socket.EndConnect (ar);
        // Here throws:
        // System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
        // ...
}
```

where `state` is a state object for receiving data from remote device, defined as a private member of the encapsulating class.

In Wireshark I see that the conversation was incomplete (flag 37):

[image]

What could cause such issues? If I run this code under Linux (C# is for Unity app) I don'

Comment: Clearly port 10200 is blocked by the firewall. What makes you think it should be open? Side note: using `Begin` `End` is really old-school, you should use `async` `await` now. And put the `Socket` in a `using` to dispose it correctly, rather than messing around with `try` `finally`

Comment: @Charlieface I think it is open as I am able to connect to it on the same machine via telnet on power shell or another C# application (with `async` `await` approach). Also turning off firewall does not help here.

Comment: I can only assume DNS is mucking something up here. Try `IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint (IpAddress.LoopBack, port);` instead of messing around with DNS, which is unnecessary for a loopback

Comment: @Charlieface yes, you were right! `IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Loopback, port);` did help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you were passing in for `host`, but if you want a loopback connection you don't need these three lines, and they wouldn't have worked if you were passing an IP address.

```cs
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry (host);
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint (ipAddress, port);
```

Instead just use `IPAddress.Loopback`

```cs
var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
```

As a side note, i strongly suggest you move to using `async` `await`, which is much easier to manage than the old `Begin` `End` style.